# Comparing an asp.net date passed as a parameter to stored procedure with a date in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, date, parameters, comparison

I've tried to compare a date passed as parameter to a stored procedure from asp.net with a date in database. But cannot yield the needed result..

My query is as follows:

```
         @date datetime

         Select * from table
         where (CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[date],112)=CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@date,112))
```

I've no issue to insert a date passed as a parameter from asp.net, the sql server takes care of the date format..

Any one please tell me how i can compare those dates..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is

```
@date datetime

Select * from table          
where [date] = @date
```

edit: if you just want to compare the date component (excluding time) in SQL2005, compare the year, month and day.

```
Select * from table          
where DATEPART(YEAR, [date]) = DATEPART(YEAR, @date)
and DATEPART(MONTH, [date]) = DATEPART(MONTH, @date)
and DATEPART(DAY, [date]) = DATEPART(DAY, @date)
```

I always prefer avoiding string comparisons.

Comment: @Kirk, I just wanted to compare only the date part (time part may be different). My date field is of the type datetime (sql server 2005 has no date type i guess?).

Comment: @harun yes sql server has Datetime and not date while Mysql have two different for Datetime  and Date

Comment: @Devjosh - SQL 2008 has date, but not SQL 2005

Comment: @Kirk, During insertion sql server takes care of the format.. But i used the string convertion to make both the dates to one format. Could you please tell me what is the issue with my string comparison?

Comment: I've given you my answer on how to compare two dates, excluding the time component. I do not suggest that you convert & compare strings. Does my answer not work for you?

Comment: @kirk,Yes it works... Using Convert(NVARCHAR,[date],112), if has no other issues can reduce the complexity, right? So i just wanted to know the problems using string comparisons..  Thank you...

Comment: @Harun - I do not agree. Unless you know the output for format code 112, is not at all clear that you are comparing only the date component. Using the DATEPART function makes your intention obvious.

Answer (score 0):

@harun can you put the code how are you passing the date in date parameter have you stored the date in DateTime type so when you write

```
CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",aspDate.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy"`);
```

it will pass only the date part to parameter.i am aassuming that your date variable is of Datetime

in sql you can extract date like following example

```
select convert(varchar(10),@date,101);
```

hope it will help